# How to align checkbox and label on prestashop

Tags: html, css, prestashop, smarty

Hi, I'm working on a prestashop module, and I want to align a checkbox with a label in a smarty template.

I try this for exemple :

```
<input id="Checkbox1" name="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="Admin" />
<label for="Checkbox1">test</label>
```

But on my navigator the label is under the checkbox, and in HTML source, I see a `div` around my `checkbox`.

```
<div class="checker" id="uniform-Checkbox1"><span><input id="Checkbox1" name="Checkbox1" value="Admin" type="checkbox"></span></div>
<label for="Checkbox1">test</label>
```

This code run perfectly in a classic HTML page.
Thanks for help.
I use Prestashop 1.6.1.4 in a docker environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste following css in your custom css file:

```
.checker,
.checker+label {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
.checker,
.checker+label {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="checker" id="uniform-Checkbox1"><span><input id="Checkbox1" name="Checkbox1" value="Admin" type="checkbox"></span></div>
<label for="Checkbox1">test</label>
```